# if and elseif issue in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, if-statement

I am trying to calculate the incentive for the people with designation as Assistant Managers and Senior Executives. So, I need to give 1% of the total amount to the Senior Executives and 1.5% to the managers. So, while writing the if, elseif conditions for the same in codeigniter view. Only the if condition is working and elseif conditiion is not working. Since, I am new to codeigniter, please help me out with this.

```
$amount = 0;


if (isset($target_revenue[0]['target'])) {
    $amount = $get_rev / $target_revenue[0]['target'] * 100; {
        if ($amount > 100 && $designation = "Assistant Manager") {

            $get_rev1 = ($get_rev - $target_revenue[0]['target']) * 0.015;
        } else if ($amount > 100 && $designation = "Senior Executive") {

            $get_rev1 = ($get_rev - $target_revenue[0]['target']) * 0.01;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Simple typo. You're not using comparison operators (`==`) but assignment operators (`=`). Change your conditions to `$designation == "Assistant Manager"` and `$designation == "Senior Executive"` and you'll be OK. For completeness sake, this is not a Codeigniter issue but a simple PHP error

Answer (score 0):

Inside both if conditions you need to add '==' instead of '='. And you can check your code syntax [here](https://phpcodechecker.com/) if you need.

```
$amount = 0;

if (isset($target_revenue[0]['target'])) {
    $amount = $get_rev / $target_revenue[0]['target'] * 100; {
        if ($amount > 100 && $designation == "Assistant Manager") {

            $get_rev1 = ($get_rev - $target_revenue[0]['target']) * 0.015;
        } else if ($amount > 100 && $designation == "Senior Executive") {

            $get_rev1 = ($get_rev - $target_revenue[0]['target']) * 0.01;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I had already tried that and after replacing = with ==, it is not displaying any output.

Comment: have you tried `echo $get_rev1;` inside if conditions?. Or weather conditions valid?

Comment: and think 1.5% is 0.15 and not 0.015 btw

Comment: @vimuth no, 0.15 is 15%

Comment: @Neha if using comparison operators is not working, there's probably something wrong with the values you're checking against. The only reason why using an assignment operator (`=`) seemed to work for the first `if` is that you were actually assigning the value "Assistant Manager" to the `$designation` variable, not because the comparison was actually working

Comment: hi,
Thank you all for your help but the problem is there is a table user in the database where the column designation stores the designations as Assistant Manager and Senior Executive. So, I need to provide incentives based on their designations but there is some issue with my designation part in the above code.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try This: **
*I don't know will it be helpful or not*

```
$amount = 0;


if (isset($target_revenue[0]['target'])){
    $amount = $get_rev / $target_revenue[0]['target'] * 100;
if ($amount > 100 && $designation = "Assistant Manager") {
    $get_rev1 = ($get_rev - $target_revenue[0]['target']) * 0.015;
} else if ($amount > 100 && $designation = "Senior Executive") {
    $get_rev1 = ($get_rev - $target_revenue[0]['target']) * 0.01;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help but still only first if condition is working in this case as well.